# Curl freezes when downloading from ftp

Tags: ftp, curl

I'm trying to download a file from ftp server using `curl`:

```
curl --user kshitiz:pAssword ftp://@11.111.11.11/myfile.txt -o /tmp/myfile.txt -v
```

`curl` connects to the server and freezes:

```
* Hostname was NOT found in DNS cache
*   Trying 11.111.11.11...
  % Total    % Received % Xferd  Average Speed   Time    Time     Time  Current
                                 Dload  Upload   Total   Spent    Left  Speed
  0     0    0     0    0     0      0      0 --:--:-- --:--:-- --:--:--     0* Connected to 11.111.11.11 (11.111.11.11) port 21 (#0)
< 220-You Are Attempting To Access a Private
< 220-Network.  Unauthorized Access is Strictly
< 220-Forbidden.  Violators Will be Prosecuted!
< 220-- Management
< 220 This is a private system - No anonymous login
> USER kshitiz
< 331 User kshitiz OK. Password required
> PASS pAssword
< 230-OK. Current directory is /
< 230 4432718 Kbytes used (54%) - authorized: 8192000 Kb
> PWD
< 257 "/" is your current location
* Entry path is '/'
  0     0    0     0    0     0      0      0 --:--:--  0:00:01 --:--:--     0> EPSV
* Connect data stream passively
* ftp_perform ends with SECONDARY: 0
  0     0    0     0    0     0      0      0 --:--:--  0:00:02 --:--:--     0< 229 Extended Passive mode OK (|||10653|)
* Hostname was NOT found in DNS cache
*   Trying 11.111.11.11...
* Connecting to 11.111.11.11 (11.111.11.11) port 10653
  0     0    0     0    0     0      0      0 --:--:--  0:00:03 --:--:--     0* Connected to 11.111.11.11 (11.111.11.11) port 21 (#0)
> TYPE A
  0     0    0     0    0     0      0      0 --:--:--  0:04:02 --:--:--     0^C
```

Connecting with `ftp` and fetching a file works however:

```
Status: Connecting to 11.1.1.11:21...
Status: Connection established, waiting for welcome message...
Response:   220-You Are Attempting To Access a Private
Response:   220-Network.  Unauthorized Access is Strictly
Response:   220-Forbidden.  Violators Will be Prosecuted!
Response:   220-- Management
Response:   220 This is a private system - No anonymous login
Command:    USER kshitiz
Response:   331 User kshitiz OK. Password required
Command:    PASS ******
Response:   230-OK. Current directory is /
Response:   230 4432718 Kbytes used (54%) - authorized: 8192000 Kb
Status: Server does not support non-ASCII characters.
Status: Connected
Status: Starting download of /myfile.txt
Command:    CWD /
Response:   250 OK. Current directory is /
Command:    PWD
Response:   257 "/" is your current location
Command:    TYPE I
Response:   200 TYPE is now 8-bit binary
Command:    PASV
Response:   227 Entering Passive Mode (10,9,4,66,39,139)
Command:    RETR myfile.txt
Response:   150 Accepted data connection
Response:   226-File successfully transferred
Response:   226 0.000 seconds (measured here), 3.39 Kbytes per second
Status: File transfer successful, transferred 1 B in 1 second
```

What's the deal with the `TYPE A` command? Why doesn't curl work when ftp does?

Comment: Forgive my ignorance but.... what makes you want to access an ftp with something like curl or wget?

Comment: @YoMismo Non-interactive script-able ftp access.

Comment: You can use ftp for that matter. Create a .netrc file in your home directory with the next format: machine 11.1.1.11 login kshitiz password pAssword after that you will be able to acces your ftp with 'here' document scritping and without user/password.

Comment: You can also use `lftp` which is a great client for ftp/ftps/sftp connections and will allow you to automate scripts with it and 'here' documents.

Comment: For curl's debugging purposes, maybe if you substitute -v with --trace you get more information about what's going on.

Comment: @YoMismo Yes there are multiple methods. But not all are feasible in a corporate environment due to policy limitations. I can't install `lftp`. The `.netrc` method will allow password less access but would it also allow non-interactive get, put, ls? I'll rather not mess with the home directory unless absolutely needed.

Comment: Yes it will, as I stated before you can use here documents. I will post it as an answer to let you know how it is done.

Comment: @YoMismo I tried `--trace`. It displays no information at all. Probably because it `Enables  a full trace dump of all incoming and outgoing data` but no data is being exchanged.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Adding `--disable-epsv` switch fixed the problem.

A little explanation:

> I just went through many hours of trying to figure out wierd FTP
>   problems.   The way that the problem presented was that after login,
>   when the FTP client attempted a directory listing (or any other
>   command), it would just hang. EPSV is "extended passive mode", and is
>   a newer extension to FTP's historical passive mode (PASV) ... most
>   recent FTP clients attempt EPSV first, and then only use the
>   traditional PASV if it fails. ... if the firewall is blocking EPSV,
>   the client will think that the command is successful [**and keep waiting for response**].

Read more [here](http://www.bartlettpublishing.com/site/bartpub/blog/3/entry/197).

Comment: Wow well done for finding this, it had me scratching my head when a script kept stopping on curl ftp downloads!

Comment: To set this as curl default: `echo no-epsv >> ~/.curlrc`

Answer (score 1):

Example of 'here' document after creating a ~/.netrc with conections/users/passwords.

```
 #!/bin/bash
 ftp 11.1.1.11 << eof
        ascii
        get /tmp/myfile.txt
        bye
 eof
```

Pitty you can't use lftp, it's a great client and I don't see any security difference between having your passwords in ~/.netrc or having them in the script if you give it the right permissions.

Comment: +1 For posting a viable alternative solution but there's a way to make `curl` work as well.

Answer (score 0):

Problem is with the ftp server running on 11.111.11.11 IP address.

This hangs forever...

ftp 11.111.11.11

First get your ftp server working with a simple ftp client.

Likely this will fix your curl command too.

Comment: Didn't I already mention that it works with FileZilla?